# What does the lpr -h command exactly mean from linux?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I am new at Linux and in my school they asked me to give an example of this command

```
lpr -h
```

I already know that `lpr` its for printing and that the option `-h` disables banner printing.

What banner? As far as I am with Linux I only know to create banners from the banner command

```
banner "hello world"
```

Not how to save it or print it. Is that kind of banner what this `-h` option refers to?

Could you give me an example?

Comment: @TomWijsman: Except it doesn't. The version of lpr(1) which comes with CUPS merely says "*Disables banner printing. This option is equivalent to "-o job-sheets=none"*."

Comment: @TomWijsman: Now what is a "job sheet"?

Comment: @TomWijsman he noted, that he found out what is written in man. the question was "What a banner is"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man lpr` --> `-h`](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/man-lpr.html) --> [`-o job-sheets=none` --> `banner page`](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html) --> [Wikipedia – Banner Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_page).

The first page explains what the command does, the second explains the options `-o` takes and the third explains what the banner page actually is; thus we obtain this paragraph from Wikipedia:

> A banner page, also called a burst page, job sheet, or a printer separator, is used in computerized printing in order to separate documents (or "print jobs") from each other and to identify the originator of the print request by username. These pages are typically used in office environments where many people share a small number of printers. In some cases, print jobs are sent to a central processing area where messengers take the printouts back to the owner, but the usual practice in modern office environments is for the user to retrieve his or her own documents. The banner page makes it clear who printed each job.

You can find examples of what banner pages look like on Google Images.

Also, I should note that the Linux `banner` command is something completely different.

<sub>You are responsible for not doing your homework yourself, not me.</sub>

Comment: am just working on my homework, thanks a lot. thats exactly what i was not able to undestand.in fact i had no idea what a burst page meant. (maybe some english problems) anyways, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @elizabeth: No problem, just want to give an example of how manuals (`man lpr`), background research (what is this `cups` thing, does it have a manual too?) and some googling (Wikipedia, Images) can help a lot. Also, I should note that the Linux `banner` command is something completely different.

Comment: @elizabeth: So, to answer the task: `lpr -h` would just result in your name, `lpr` would add a banner.